# HadoopImageProcessingInterface (HIPI) SamplePrograms

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

I am working on HIPI and getting started on a sample program.

I am unable to executed it, as it is always giving following exception:

```
hadoop jar Desktop/edureka/workspace/jars/SampleProgramHIPI.jar hdfs:/video/sampleimages.hib hdfs:/video/sampleimages.output
15/10/16 15:59:53 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: hipi/imagebundle/mapreduce/ImageBundleInputFormat
    at SampleProgram.run(SampleProgram.java:67)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
    at SampleProgram.main(SampleProgram.java:86)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.ImageBundleInputFormat
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 10 more
```

Build path is already updated with the given library (hipi/core/build/libs/hipi-2.1.0.jar).

Checked almost everywhere!! Please help me.

Following is the sample program, I am trying to execute:

```
package hipi.image.examples;
import hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.ImageBundleInputFormat;
import hipi.image.FloatImage;
import hipi.image.ImageHeader;
//import org.hipi.imagebundle.mapreduce.HibInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configured;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.Tool;
import org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import java.io.IOException; 
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class SampleProgram extends Configured implements Tool { 
  public static class HelloWorldMapper extends Mapper<ImageHeader, FloatImage, IntWritable, FloatImage> {
    public void map(ImageHeader key, FloatImage value, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
         if (value != null && value.getWidth() > 1 && value.getHeight() > 1 && value.getBands() == 3) {           
            int w = value.getWidth();
            int h = value.getHeight();
            float[] valData = value.getData();
            float[] avgData = {0,0,0};
            for (int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
              for (int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
                avgData[0] += valData[(j*w+i)*3+0]; 
                avgData[1] += valData[(j*w+i)*3+1]; 
                avgData[2] += valData[(j*w+i)*3+2]; 
              }
            }
            FloatImage avg = new FloatImage(1, 1, 3, avgData);
            avg.scale(1.0f/(float)(w*h));          
            context.write(new IntWritable(1), avg);
          } 
    }
  }
  public static class HelloWorldReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable, FloatImage, IntWritable, Text> {
    public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<FloatImage> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        FloatImage avg = new FloatImage(1, 1, 3);
        int total = 0;
        for (FloatImage val : values) {
          avg.add(val);
          total++;
        }
        if (total > 0) {
          avg.scale(1.0f / total);         
    float[] avgData = avg.getData();
          String result = String.format("Average pixel value: %f %f %f", avgData[0], avgData[1], avgData[2]);       
          context.write(key, new Text(result));
        }
    }
  }
  public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if (args.length != 2) {
      System.out.println("Usage: helloWorld <input HIB> <output directory>");
      System.exit(0);
    }  
    Job job = Job.getInstance();
    job.setInputFormatClass(ImageBundleInputFormat.class);  
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    job.setJarByClass(SampleProgram.class);
    job.setMapperClass(HelloWorldMapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(HelloWorldReducer.class);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(FloatImage.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);    

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);    
    return success ? 0 : 1;
  }  
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ToolRunner.run(new SampleProgram(), args);
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try with libjars option as shown below. The libjars uploads the given jars to the cluster and then makes them available on the classpath for each mapper,reducer instance. You can use HADOOP_CLASSPATH env variable if you would like to add additional libraries(jars) to the driver client classpath.

```
export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=hipi-0.0.1.jar
hadoop jar ~/Desktop/edureka/workspace/jars/SampleProgramHIPI.jar hipi.image.examples.SampleProgram hdfs:/video/sampleimages.hib hdfs:/video/sampleimages.output
```

Comment: Thanks Sarath for your valuable inputs.

Comment: I had been changed HIPI to previous version 2.0 and built with buld.xml.